# R: Writing a function to see if plant height increases monotonically

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm writing a function to check if the height of plants follows a monotonic growth.
Since there's NA in the data, which doesn't directly invalidate the assumption, I'd like these to be filled from the top down, and if the first value in a series is NA, this should be filled from the bottom up. How do I specify that I'd like series with no recorded heights to be left at NA?

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
plantid <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), times=c(3,3,3,3,3))
year <- rep(1:3, length.out=length(plantid))
height <- c(1,2,3,1,NA,3,3,2,1,NA,2,3,1,3,2)
plant.df <- data.frame(plantid,year,height)
```

However, when asking if there's a break (decrease) in the growth trend of a plant individual, my dplyr responds`TRUE` for everything.

```
plant.df %>% group_by(plantid, year) %>% 
      arrange(plantid, year) %>%
      tidyr::fill(height, direction="downup") %>% 
      mutate(monotonic_growth = all(height==cummax(height)))
```

Expected output:

```
monotonic_growth<- c(rep(TRUE, 3), rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE,3), rep(FALSE,3))
cbind(plant.df,monotonic_growth)
```

Is there any way to avoid the all() so I can sort more detailed later? i.e. expected output:

```
monotonic_growth <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)
cbind(plant.df,monotonic_growth)
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: I'm confused ... is this question about monotonic growth, or is it about `NA`-filling? (BTW, your code referenced `direction=`, but in the function (in tidyr-1.0.0, at least) it is `.direction=`.)

Comment: The reason you are over-grouping: because you have one observation per `plantid` *and* `year`, `fill` has nothing to fill from. Perhaps just `group_by(plantid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-grouping. Because you have no more than one observation per `plantid` *and* `year`, `tidyr::fill` only ever sees one value, and when `NA` there is nothing to impute from. Group by `plantid` only.

```r
plant.df %>%
  group_by(plantid) %>% 
  arrange(plantid, year) %>%
  tidyr::fill(height, .direction="downup") %>%
  mutate(monotonic_growth = all(height==cummax(height))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 15 x 4
#    plantid  year height monotonic_growth
#      <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <lgl>           
#  1       1     1      1 TRUE            
#  2       1     2      2 TRUE            
#  3       1     3      3 TRUE            
#  4       2     1      1 TRUE            
#  5       2     2      1 TRUE            
#  6       2     3      3 TRUE            
#  7       3     1      3 FALSE           
#  8       3     2      2 FALSE           
#  9       3     3      1 FALSE           
# 10       4     1      2 TRUE            
# 11       4     2      2 TRUE            
# 12       4     3      3 TRUE            
# 13       5     1      1 FALSE           
# 14       5     2      3 FALSE           
# 15       5     3      2 FALSE
```

An alternative to your `all` call is to use `diff`. Two variants:

1. If this year's `height` is greater than or equal to last year's:

   ```r
   plant.df %>%
     group_by(plantid) %>%
     arrange(plantid, year) %>%
     tidyr::fill(height, .direction="downup") %>%
     mutate(monotonic_growth = c(TRUE, diff(height) > 0)) %>%
     ungroup()
   # # A tibble: 15 x 4
   #    plantid  year height monotonic_growth
   #      <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <lgl>           
   #  1       1     1      1 TRUE            
   #  2       1     2      2 TRUE            
   #  3       1     3      3 TRUE            
   #  4       2     1      1 TRUE            
   #  5       2     2      1 FALSE           
   #  6       2     3      3 TRUE            
   #  7       3     1      3 TRUE            
   #  8       3     2      2 FALSE           
   #  9       3     3      1 FALSE           
   # 10       4     1      2 TRUE            
   # 11       4     2      2 FALSE           
   # 12       4     3      3 TRUE            
   # 13       5     1      1 TRUE            
   # 14       5     2      3 TRUE            
   # 15       5     3      2 FALSE
   ```

   This shows you where you have increasing growth.
2. You can extend this to include monotonic growth up until it isn't, with `cumall`:

   ```r
   plant.df %>%
     group_by(plantid) %>%
     arrange(plantid, year) %>%
     tidyr::fill(height, .direction="downup") %>%
     mutate(monotonic_growth = cumall(c(TRUE, diff(height) > 0))) %>%
     ungroup()
   # # A tibble: 15 x 4
   #    plantid  year height monotonic_growth
   #      <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <lgl>           
   #  1       1     1      1 TRUE            
   #  2       1     2      2 TRUE            
   #  3       1     3      3 TRUE            
   #  4       2     1      1 TRUE            
   #  5       2     2      1 FALSE           
   #  6       2     3      3 FALSE           
   #  7       3     1      3 TRUE            
   #  8       3     2      2 FALSE           
   #  9       3     3      1 FALSE           
   # 10       4     1      2 TRUE            
   # 11       4     2      2 FALSE           
   # 12       4     3      3 FALSE           
   # 13       5     1      1 TRUE            
   # 14       5     2      3 TRUE            
   # 15       5     3      2 FALSE
   ```